# what means "undimmed by time, unbound by death"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

So the full line is

**If we have souls**,

**They are made of love we share**

**Undimmed by time, unbound by death**

I didn't quite understand what the write meant by undimmed by time.Is it means that the souls will get brighter as the time passes? or something else.
Souls are connected.Is unbound means they brake the chain of body and mind by death?

Comment: Undimmed by time means not dimmed (diminished) by the passage of time.  Unbound by  death means not bound (restrained or limited) by death (when a person dies)

Comment: They are *eternal*, *everlasting*, or *permanent*.

Comment: So, If I'm correct, Undimmed by time meant souls are everlasting thing that doesn't decay while traveling forward through time.Unbound by death meant souls get free from the body by death.